# echo meta description with product name

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, simple-product

I want to echo Meta description which will also pull the name of the product.

So far I have:

```
<?php echo '<meta name="xxx" />' ?>
```

I want the "xxx" to be  the product name but unsure of how to do this.

I have tried this:

```
<?php echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name').'" />' ?>
```

this is clearly wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get product details in head.phtml follow below comment

```
// Get product name
if($currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product')) {
     $currentProduct->getName();
}
```

Comment: Be sure to check whether `Mage::registry('current_product)` exists at all, otherwise, might generate exceptions of calling method on non-object.

Comment: It works great. thank you :) the `;` at the end through me off, but I removed it and it works fine.